# How do I set the selected state of an image button with xml

Tags: xml, android, user-interface, imagebutton

I have an image button as defined below.

```
<ImageButton 
    android:text="Play"
    android:src="@drawable/playpause"
    android:background="@drawable/opaque" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/player_ctrl_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I want to set the default state of the button to be selected.  So in code I would say:

`playBtn.setSelected(true);`

Is it possible to do this in xml?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can -- sorry!

Comment: Why is this an acceptable answer? You CAN do this by referencing another xml that has your selected states defined. If you do not have multiple images (one selected and one not selected) use opacity to simulate an impression

Comment: @portfoliobuilder That's not what the question was asking.

Comment: Check the answers below!

Answer (score 15):

A newer solution to the problem would be to use `DataBinding`.

1. Create a `@BindingAdapter` (somewhere in your code):

```
@BindingAdapter("is_selected")
fun setSelected(view: View, selected: Boolean) {
    view.isSelected = selected
}
```

2. Use `DataBinding` in your `xml`

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
    </data>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/player_ctrl_btn"
        is_selected="@{true}"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/opaque"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="0px"
        android:src="@drawable/playpause"
        android:text="Play" />
</layout>
```

---

**IMPORTANT:** remember that you need to use `DataBinding` here. So you cannot simply call add `is_selected="true"` (because it will fail not telling you about it), you need to add `is_selected="@{true}"`

Comment: Answer by Nicholas clarifying `BindingAdapter` seems better

Comment: Well, it's 6 months younger and I guess it made all the difference because it was not working like that when I was writing this answer 

Answer (score 7):

No need to create BindingAdapter method, just enable `DataBidning` and type:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
</data>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/player_ctrl_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/opaque"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="0px"
    android:src="@drawable/playpause"
    android:text="Play"
    app:selected="@{true}" />
</layout>
```

Comment: not working....